# How do I set default value of an integer in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm new to mongodb and node.js. Let me know, how do I set default value after creating the user.

Here is my current code:

```
// CREATE USER
app.post("/user/create", function (req, res) {
    var user = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password,
        email: req.body.email,
        //changes made
        win: req.body.win,
        lose: req.body.lose,
        draw: req.body.draw
    });
    user.save(function (err, user) {
        if (err)
            res.json(err)
        //res.end('Registration '+user.username +' Ok!');
        req.session.loggedIn = true;
        res.redirect('/user/' + user.username);
    });
});
```

I want that my win, lose, draw fields are set to 0 after creating a user. In my user schema they are declared as 'Numbers'.

Comment: Are you using mongoose?

Comment: If you're using mongoose, you'd just add a default to the properties: `var userSchema = new Schema({  win: { type: Number, default: 0 } })`

Comment: yes I am using mongoose

Comment: Thanks man. this worked out well for me. I didn't know I could do this.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

As you're using Mongoose, you can set the default as part of the `Schema` definition:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({ 
    win: { type: Number, default: 0 }
});
```

The options are documented [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-default). It's also cool that if you set the default to a function, it will execute when the Model is instantiated. For example, if it were: `default: Date.now`, it will call the `Date.now()` function when a model is created.

Comment: I am not familiar with subdirectories yet because I am just starting with node and mongodb, so i'll keep things simple for now and get to that in the later stages of my learning. Thanks though! I solved this problem.

Comment: Is it okay to email you kind sir? I have a question regarding the little project I have made and I have further problems with my mongodb